# How to see speed of PCI-X card?

Tags: command-line

Googling for this question gives a lot of answers based on PCIe. Unfortunately, I'm not looking for PCIe based answers at the moment. I have an older PC that still contains some PCI-X slots (y'know, like good old PCI but longer and faster). At the moment I have an Auzentech X-Meridian 7.1 2G installed in the PCI slot, and an HP Firewire 800 card in one of my PCI-X slots. When I run `# lspci -vvv -s 08:` I get the following output, showing both cards. Is the Firewire one running at 66+MHz and in 64 bit mode, or?

```
08:04.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
    Subsystem: AuzenTech, Inc. X-Meridian 7.1 2G
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (500ns min, 6000ns max)
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: I/O ports at 5000 [size=256]
    Capabilities: [c0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Kernel driver in use: snd_oxygen
    Kernel modules: snd_oxygen

08:08.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB22A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [iOHCI-Lynx] (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Device b380
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32 (500ns min, 1000ns max), Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20
    Region 0: Memory at d0e04000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Region 1: Memory at d0e00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME+
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your card is running at 33MHz in 32-bit mode. For a 64-bit, 66MHz PCI-X device you’d see `66MHz+` in the `Status` line, and you’d also have a `68` capability section like

```
    Capabilities: [68] PCI-X non-bridge device
            Command: DPERE- ERO- RBC=512 OST=8
            Status: Dev=03:04.1 64bit+ 133MHz+ SCD- USC- DC=simple DMMRBC=2048 DMOST=8 DMCRS=16 RSCEM- 266MHz- 533MHz-
```

(that’s a 133MHz device; you’d expect at least `64bit+` here).

Comment: Thanks! I indeed saw that on the datasheet of the controller just now. Should've tought of that before asking this question.